# How do I loop through the sub property of a class?

Tags: c#, list, loops, reflection, properties

I have a client class and one of the properties is Emails which is a list of strings.  I can loop through the properties of the class to output the values, but when it gets to the Emails property it doesn't loop through the emails because it needs to do another loop through the list.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in oClient.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (prop.Name.ToUpper().ToString() == "EMAILS")
    {
        //need code to loop through emails
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<b>" + prop.Name.ToString() + "</b>: " + prop.GetValue(oClient, null) + "<br />");
    }
}
```

Comment: Emails is of which type, List<string>? You could cast it, like ((List<string>prop).ForEach(x => "<b>" + x + "</b">)

Comment: I started going the route of foreach(string str in prop) but it was raising an error.  I then tried Google and couldn't find anything specific enough.  So then I came here.

Comment: @Curtis: Is `Emails` a collection?

Comment: It's a list...public List<string> Emails { get; set; }

Comment: Then probably @Rup's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the value of Emails using

```
Object emails = prop.GetValue(oClient, null);
```

and then iterate through that, e.g.

```
IEnumerable<String> emailsEnumerable = emails as IEnumerable<String>;
if (emailsEnumerable != null) {
    foreach(string emailValue in emailsEnumerable) {
        // ...
    }
}
```